# How can I stop extra rerenders in my component when I rely on a usePrevious?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So my googling did not return any useful results, so sorry if I ask a duplicate question.

So I am listening to my redux-store in react with 2 selectors.  1 to get the oldest timestamp we have, and another to get all messages in the store.

```
// returns an array
  const messages = useSelector(
    (store) => selectMessages(store, chatId),
    shallowEqual
  );

  const [showGetMore, setShowGetMore] = useState(true);

// returns a firebase timestamp
  const oldestMessage= useSelector((store) =>
    selectOldestMessage(store, chatId)
  );

// uses the react hook usePrevious code
  const previousOldestTimestamp = usePrevious(
    // if oldestMessage is undefined still, set it as null,
    // so the getMore doesn't disappear
    oldestMessage || null
  );


  useEffect(() => {
    if (previousOldestTimestamp === oldestMessage) {
      // if timestamps are equal, there are no more old messages to get
      setShowGetMore(false);
    }
  }, [
    previousOldestTimestamp,
    oldestMessage,
    setShowGetMore,
  ]);
```

So when I click to get more messages, i make a call that calls firebase for more messages, then it sends 2 actions, 1 to update the messages object, and another to update the oldest message field.
However, using a props/state watcher, my selectOldestMessages sometimes rerenders with the same number of objects in the array, even though I am using shallowEquals to prevent that, and the useEffect is always running and declaring that the timestamps are the same, when in the store they are always updating correctly.

So I assume it's because the 2 actions I dispatch are triggering the component to re render 2 times which causes the usePrevious hook to run 2 times which breaks my code because it should only being re rendered 1 time.

But if I am dead wrong, I would love to know.
Does anyone have a better solution for this, or see a bad react coding pattern?

Comment: What does `selectMessages` and `selectOldestMessage` do ?

Comment: What makes you think that 2 independent subscriptions to the store should only trigger a single rerender? The `showGetMore` seems to me to be derived state and a good candidate to ***not*** be stored in local state. Maybe instead of using a `usePrevious` hook to cache a value from the previous render cycle you just store it in a local React ref and only update it in an `useEffect` when the dependency updates. This avoids any "mismatches" just because the component rerendered (*for any reason*).

Comment: selectMessages gets an array of all chat messages, selectOldestMessage gets the timestamp of the oldest message.

And thanks, I will look into a ref option